# Apache Drill slow response

Tags: json, apache-drill

I have a JSON file with the following structure:

```
[
  {
    "metric": "MyMovie",
    "tags": {
      "channel": "999"
    },
    "dps": {
      "1448942420": 1,
      "1448942421": 4,
      "1448942422": 7,
      "1448942423": 2,
      ....
    }
  }
]
```

And I'm using `Apache Drill` to query this json file. My sql looks like this:

```
select 
  t.tags.channel as channel, 
  t.metric, 
  FLATTEN(KVGEN(t.dps)) as dps 
from dfs.`/c:/myJson.json` t;
```

And this sql is running fine if the json file is small (100Kb - 1Mb). But if the json file is more than 1Mb its taking very long time before any data is returned and the ram usage is very high (5-6GB).

The biggest data i can have in the json file is ~5mb in which the `dps` section contains ~300k rows

Is this normal behaviour or im doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Drill cannot split json files so if all your data is in a single file the scan won't be done in parallel. Try splitting the data into several small files and you should see an improvement in the query speed.

Not sure about the high memory usage.